# Word meaning anthropomorphize, but specifically regarding sexual characteristics?

Tags: single-word-requests

To ***anthropomorphize*** is "to attribute human personality or form to things not human." [[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anthropomorphize)]

Is there a word that means "to attribute human sexual traits to things not human?" Think Bugs Bunny dressed in drag, Miss Piggy, etc.

The word ***sexualize*** might work, but it doesn't necessarily indicate that the subject is not human.

Comment: The question becomes one of whether you intend morphological sexual traits (genitalia), or emotional, or?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the distinction, since anthropomorphism covers both cases. I guess I'm primarily thinking morphologically, though - not about genitalia per se, but other traits that imply human sexuality - things like plump lips, shapely legs or posterior, or broad, muscular shoulders. Some other tangible examples might be Ms. Pac-Man (long eyelashes, lipstick, blush, hair bow, shapely legs) or the green M&M (raised eyebrows, gloves, heeled boots; similar feminized sexuality).